# change float display order on overflow-y

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float, overflow

Can someone show me how to order the columns below ([jsbin starter](http://jsbin.com/zovoguqe/1)) so that as the screen gets smaller the last column is always displayed, the first column is hidden first, the second column is hidden next, etc..? (If there is a way around not using media queries that'd be ideal.)

**HTML**

```
<nav>1st column</nav>
<main>
  <article>2nd column</article>
  <article>3rd column</article>
  <article>4th column</article>
</main>
```

Comment: Why not just use media queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Is there a way without using them? Was hoping so since overflow-y is in place.

Comment: if you do not want to use media queries, then you need javaScript to check on screen width. media queries is the way via CSS

Comment: I didn't want to be stuck with width values since all the columns will eventually be different widths.

Comment: Here's a [jsbin with media queries](http://jsbin.com/zovoguqe/4). Anybody got a better idea?

Comment: @Jeffrey If you change the ordering of your html, you wouldn't need to use any media queries etc. Just do it as 4th, 3rd, 2nd, 1st...

Comment: @Omega - not all the columns are floated so I don't believe that will work, plus the html order needs to remain the same for accessibility reasons. Thanks though